# Testing listeners with Queue::fake()

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking

My Laravel 5.5 application has a `Product` model. The `Product` model has a `dispatchesEvents` property that looks like this:

```
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => ProductCreated::class,
    'updated' => ProductUpdated::class,
    'deleted' => ProductDeleted::class
];
```

I also have a listener that is called `CreateProductInMagento` which is mapped to the `ProductCreated` event in the `EventServiceProvider`. This listener implements the `ShouldQueue` interface.

When a product is created, the `ProductCreated` event is fired and the `CreateProductInMagento` listener is pushed to the queue and is run.

I am now trying to write a test for all of this. Here is what I have:

```
/** @test */
public function a_created_product_is_pushed_to_the_queue_so_it_can_be_added_to_magento()
{
    Queue::fake();

    factory(Product::class)->create();

    Queue::assertPushed(CreateProductInMagento::class);
}
```

But I get a `The expected [App\Listeners\Magento\Product\CreateProductInMagento] job was not pushed.` error message.

**How do I test queueable listeners using Laravel's `Queue::fake()` method?**

Comment: try `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: I started the command you mentioned and then tried to run the test. Same error.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem here is that the listener is not the job pushed to the queue. Instead, there's a `Illuminate\Events\CallQueuedListener` job that is queued and will in turn call the appropriate listener when resolved.

So you could do your assertion like this:

```
Queue::assertPushed(CallQueuedListener::class, function ($job) {
    return $job->class == CreateProductInMagento::class;
});
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. My test passes now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @alepeino This helped. However, I still couldn't find any info about this in the lravel docs. Could you please share any links related on this. Appreciate.

Comment: This is so annoying, somebody should make a PR :) Developers shouldn't care about framework internals (classes like CallQueuedListener - that can change any time)

Comment: The equivalent class for testing commands queued using `Artisan::queue(...)` is `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand`.

Answer (score 3):

Running `artisan queue:work` won't solve the issue because when testing, Laravel is configured to use the `sync` driver, which just runs jobs synchronously in your tests. I am not sure why the job is not being pushed, though I would guess it has to do with Laravel handling events differently in tests. Regardless, there is a better approach you can take to writing your tests that should both fix the issue and make your code more extendable.

In your `ProductTest`, rather than testing that `a_created_product_is_pushed_to_the_queue_so_it_can_be_added_to_magento`, you should simply test that the event is fired. Your `ProductTest` doesn't care what the `ProductCreated` event is; that is the job of a `ProductCreatedTest`. So, you can use [Event Faking](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mocking#event-fake) to change your test a bit:

```
/** @test */
public function product_created_event_is_fired_upon_creation()
{
    Event::fake();

    factory(Product::class)->create();

    Event::assertDispatched(ProductCreated::class);
}
```

Then, create a new `ProductCreatedTest` to unit test your `ProductCreated` event. This is where you should place the assertion that a job is pushed to the queue:

```
/** @test */
public function create_product_in_magento_job_is_pushed()
{
    Queue::fake();

    // Code to create/handle event.

    Queue::assertPushed(CreateProductInMagento::class);
}
```

This has the added benefit of making your code easier to change in the future, as your tests now more closely follow the practice of only testing the class they are responsible for. Additionally, it should solve the issue you're having where the events fired from a model aren't queuing up your jobs.

Comment: thanks for the feed back. I added the line `event(new ProductCreated($product));` in your second test where you have `// Code to create/handle event.`. That test still fails with the same error message. Should I be doing something differently or configure phpunit somehow?

Comment: That's interesting. I've worked a lot with queues but not much with events. To be sure, you registered both an event **and** listener [as defined in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#registering-events-and-listeners) ?

Comment: Yep, here is the line from my `EventServiceProvider`: https://ibb.co/da659R