# Notification test fails when using Event::fake() or Queue::fake()

Tags: laravel

I created a test for notification. The notification was triggered via an event, processed by a listener. The test works just fine when I test only using `Notification::fake()`.

Here is how my test looks like:

`Feature\FieldReportTest.php`

```php
public function testStoreShouldBeAbleToTagAndNotifyTaggedUsersWhenProvided()
{
    // Queue::fake();
    // Event::fake();
    // Event::assertNotDispatched(UserTagged::class);
    Notification::fake();
    Notification::assertNothingSent();
    // Queue::assertNothingPushed();

    $company = Company::factory()->createOne([
        'user_id' => $this->user->id,
    ]);

    $branch = Branch::factory()->createOne([
        'user_id' => $company->user_id,
        'company_id' => $company->id
    ]);

    $taggedUsers = User::factory(3)->create();

    $new = FieldReport::factory()->makeOne([
        'user_id' => $this->user->id,
        'company_id' => $company->id,
        'branch_id' => $branch->id,
        'tagged_users' => $taggedUsers->pluck('id'),
    ])->toArray();

    $this->actingAs($this->user->assignRole('employee'), 'api')
        ->postJson(route('fieldReports.store'), $new)
        ->assertCreated()
        ->assertJsonFragment($taggedUsers->first()->toArray());

    // Event::assertDispatched(UserTagged::class);
    // Event::assertDispatchedTimes(UserTagged::class, 1);
    // Queue::assertPushed(
    //     CallQueuedListener::class,
    //     fn ($job) => $job->class == SendUserTaggedNotification::class,
    // );
    Notification::assertSentTo($taggedUsers->all(), UserTaggedNotification::class);
    Notification::assertTimesSent(3, UserTaggedNotification::class);
}
```

The test are failing when I uncomment `Queue::fake();` or `Event::fake()`.

```
  • Tests\Feature\FieldReportTest > store should be able to tag and notify tagged users when provided
  The expected [App\Notifications\UserTaggedNotification] notification was not sent.
  Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I've googled similar questions and tried some of the accepted answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083893/testing-listeners-with-queuefake) and still can't make it works. So, what is the proper way to make sure my app's event-listener and queue system runs as expected? I would like to test the them because they are all linked.

**UPDATE**

Maybe the provided information aren't enough to replicate the problem. To be clear about how the notification dispatched, here I provide my script for dispatching the event, please have a look..

`Models\FieldReport.php`

```php
/**
 * Register new data given by the client.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return FieldReport
 */
public function register($data)
{
    $data = collect($data);
    $registry = $data->except(['images', 'tagged_users'])->toArray();
    $registry = request()->user()->fieldReports()->create($registry);

    $this->storeImages($registry, $data);
    $this->assignAndNotifyTaggedUsers($registry, $data);
    return $registry->load('author', 'images', 'taggedUsers');
}

/**
 * Store images and attach relationships for each images.
 *
 * @param \App\Models\FieldReport $registry
 * @param \Illuminate\Support\Collection $data
 * @return void
 */
public function storeImages($registry, $data)
{
    ... // irrelevant
}

/**
 * Assign tagged users into registry and let them know
 * that they are tagged by the author.
 *
 * @param \App\Models\FieldReport $registry
 * @param \Illuminate\Support\Collection $data
 * @return void
 */
public function assignAndNotifyTaggedUsers($registry, $data)
{
    if ($registry && $data->has('tagged_users')) {
        $tagged = $registry->taggedUsers()->sync(
            $data->get('tagged_users')
        );

        if (collect($tagged)->isNotEmpty()) {
            UserTagged::dispatch($registry, 'Field Report');
        }
    }
}
```

`Events\UserTagged.php`

```php
class UserTagged
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $model;
    public $subject;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model, $subject)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
}
```

`Listeners\SendUserTaggedNotification.php`

```php
class SendUserTaggedNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserTagged  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserTagged $event)
    {
        $event->model->taggedUsers->each(
            fn ($user) => $user->notify(
                new UserTaggedNotification($event->model, $event->subject)
            )
        );
    }
}
```